# How to fetch recent 3 post from a blog table: magento

Tags: php, database, magento, blogs, posts

I have a table in database as "neotheme_blog_post" and there are many post in there, now i want to fetch recent 3 posts from this table and show them on home page:  I have tried to fetch the data as follows but nothing worked:

```
    <?php $connection = 
      Mage::getSingleton('core/resource')->getConnection('core_read');
      $query      = "Select * FROM 'neotheme_blog_post'";
      $rows       = $connection->fetchAll($query);

      foreach ($rows as $values) {
      echo $name = $values['name'];

      }?>
```

Comment: What exactly does not work? Please add some more details: Did the query not return any data. Was it wrong data? Any errors?

Comment: yeah query not return data at all. and it give an error on page load

Comment: But now i got the data... i have to filter it ..

Comment: i got this array now i can get the elements seperately?

Array ( [0] => 
        Array ( [entity_id] => 1 [created_at] => 2016-01-28 06:15:28            [updated_at] => 2016-01-28 08:25:53 [status] => 1 [title] => Gold As A Solid Investment [author] => John [post_date] => 2016-01-28 11:13:42 [summary] =>
The currency crisis is coming. There's no mistaking what we're all watching on the news and feeling in the air. It's almost tangible. @Fuzzzzel

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In my case i get the three recent posts as like follows using neotheme blog extension:

```
     $connection = 
     Mage::getSingleton('core/resource')->getConnection('core_read');
     $query = "Select * FROM neotheme_blog_post ORDER BY created_at DESC LIMIT 3 ";
     $rows = $connection->fetchAll($query);
     foreach ($rows as $values) {
     $post_titile = $values['cms_identifier'];
     echo '<div>';
     echo '<h1>' . $name = $values['title'] . '</h1>';
     echo $summery = $values['summary'];
     echo '<a href="' . $this->getUrl().'blog/'.  $post_titile . '">Read More</a>';
      echo '</div>';
```

Answer (score 2):

You may use [LIMIT](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/limit-optimization.html) over here.

```
$connection = Mage::getSingleton('core/resource')->getConnection('core_read');
$query      = "Select * FROM neotheme_blog_post LIMIT 3";
$rows       = $connection->fetchAll($query);
foreach ($rows as $values){
echo $name = $values['name'];
}
```

Comment: You're welcome :) You can also use ORDER BY for latest posts.

Comment: Right now i have just added one post in database let me post some more and check if it worked for 3 limits